# ALSA: failed to import hw:0 use case configuration -2

Tags: linux, audio, embedded-linux, alsa

I have stored the configuration for my sound card in an asound.state file and alsactl is reading it fine, but during boot and whenever I try running the command manually, this message appears in the log:

```
alsa-lib ../../../git/src/ucm/main.c:1412:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:0 use case configuration -2
```

I don't understand what is going wrong and I haven't found much online. Any ideas for how I could fix this error or what might be the origin of it?

This is what I get if I run `aplay -l`:

```
~# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: mycard [mycard], device 0: 44004000.audio-controller-tlv320aic31xx-hifi tlv320aic31xx-hifi [44004000.audio-controller-tlv320aic31xx-hifi tlv320aic31xx-hifi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more investigation, I've found this command that has removed the error message:

```
alsactl --no-ucm restore
```

Adding that `--no-ucm` part has fixed it, so the problem was probably that my sound card doesn't support UCM.